# How can I handle JSON strings in UniData?

Tags: json, u2, unidata

I am receiving JSON strings from a web service. Is there any JSON parsers for UniData?

I am on version 7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade to UniData 7.3.x, you will indeed get access to a JSON (and more) parser.

check out the manuals for a new feature called 'U2 Dynamic Objects' - UDO for short.

This will allow you to serialize, access, modified, etc JSON strings.